# Dynamic Thymeleaf include

Tags: include, thymeleaf

Is it possible to use to do a dynamic Thymeleaf include like this:

```
<div th:each="module : ${report.modules}" th:include="modules/${module.key} :: ${module.key}"></div>
```

I get a 500 when loading the page:
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "module.key"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible but you need to rebuild your template little bit. Because `th:include` is processed before `th:each` you need wrap `div` with `th:include` to iteration tag. Also path to template must be `String` so you can't do `modules/$module.key` as it's not produce desired result I suppose. See example below.

```
<th:block th:each="module : ${report.modules}">
<div th:include="${#strings.concat('modules/', module.key)} :: ${module.key}"></div>
</th:block>
```